# What MAC address should I use for my Thunderbolt Ethernet on a MBPR?

Tags: macos, thunderbolt, ethernet

I use MAC addresses to assign static IPs on my network and have recently added a new MacBook Pro Retina with Thunderbolt adapters in stead of Ethernet ports. On the box one MAC address is given for the "Ethernet" but when I plug in to the Thunderbolt ports using the Ethernet-Thunderbolt adapter, I see a different MAC address for this connection.

Which MAC address does the DCHP server see when assigning IP addresses?

---

I should add that the Ethernet-Thunderbolt adapter doesn't seem to work at all for me. It either incorrectly reports that no cable is connected, or self-assigns an IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an interface self-assigns an IP it generally means the interface isn't getting any response from your router or DHCP server. This is a feature of OS X to let the machines build an adhoc network when they cannot determine the actual network they're on -- you can put a bunch of Macs on a dumb hub and almost get them to self-organize and function with this feature.

Your router and DHCP server are going to see the MAC address listed for the device in the Network Preferences pane. Go to `System Preferences -> Network` and click on your Thunderbolt interface. Click on the `Advanced...` button and then on the `Hardware` tab:

[image: MAC Address]

That's the MAC address that your interface is broadcasting on the network when it's trying to acquire an IP on your network from your DHCP server.

Comment: Thanks! It *looks* like that fixes it. Odd thought that the MAC address listed on the box is therefor (apparently) invisible and irrelevant to network configuration.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I think you mean that when the Thunderbolt/Ethernet adapter is "not connected", there is no MAC address shown for it (even though it appears in the list of interfaces on the Network preferences), right?  I don't think that information is retained after the device is disconnected.